# How do I get the line number matching exactly my search query?

Tags: linux, shell

I have to print the line number which matching the exact word in a file. So i am using grep -w command but i am getting multiple matches.

For example

```
     grep -nw "\babc\b" /tmp/test.json
 272:{"name": "abc", "imagen": "Application1.png"},
 273:{"name": "abc-bcdgroup-deSSL", "imagen": "Application1.png"},
 274:{"name": "abc-fb-na", "imagen": "Application1.png"},
 275:{"name": "abc-gf3-bmw-comSSL", "imagen": "Application1.png"},
```

if i search for abc then it should print only

```
272:{"name": "abc", "imagen": "Application1.png"}
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: `grep -w` treats `-` as a non-word character, so `abc-bcd` matches `\babc\b`, as expected.  If your definition of "word" is "string bounded by double-quotes", then `grep -w` is the wrong tool.  What is your definition of a "word"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below command:

```
grep -nw "\"abc\"" /tmp/test.json
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP is looking for, but I wonder about input that looks like `{"name": "def\"abc", "imagen": "Application1.png"},`

Answer (score 0):

Try with start and end anchors,

```
grep -nw "^abc$" /tmp/test.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `-P` ?

```
$ grep -P '(^|\s)\Kabc(?=\s|$)' /tmp/test.json
```